# Query buttons present inside ng-content in angular

Tags: angular

I want to query buttons present inside ng-content.

[Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tq6dzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fitem.directive.ts)

html:

```
 <div appItem>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
```

ts:

```
ViewChildren(ItemDirective) buttons: QueryList<ItemDirective>;

  constructor() {}
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.buttons);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.buttons);
  }
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appItem]'
})
export class ItemDirective {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Query list does not provide the list of buttons. Other things are present in it. How can I get the list of buttons in queryList?

I have tried ViewChildren and ContentChildren (both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `appItem` in the `button` element itself.

```
<button appItem>Button X</button>
```

[Forked Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-btjehp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fitem.directive.ts)

Answer (score 2):

use `ContentChildren` instead of `ViewChildren`

```
ContentChildren(ItemDirective) buttons: QueryList<ItemDirective>;
```